# Alternativa a system("PAUSE") c++

Tags: c++

Hola estoy buscando una alternativa a system("PAUSE") ya que para que mi programa se complete correctamente le suelo introducir esta sentencia. Normalmente un programa en c++ suele tener el siguiente formato:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Empezare preguntado a algún experto en c++ que significa exactamente `return 0` porque cuando la sentencia salta el programa finaliza, creo es su función sino estoy equivocado. Entonces tengo un programa que necesito utilizar `system("PAUSE")` para que no salte la excepción ya que sino el programa no se completa, es decir da error y no puede finalizar. Entonces que alternativa a `system("PAUSE")` me recomiendan usar para que el programa no se cierre y finalice correctamente..

Comment: `return 0` es para decirle al sistema operativo: "*Hey, el programa ha finalizado sin problemas*". Si devuelves [algo diferente a 0](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/EXIT_status) el sistema operativo interpreta que tu programa finalizó con fallos.

Comment: pues en muchos programas si no pongo el pause finaliza con fallos no hay alguna alternativa a system("PAUSE") puedo intentar ser más especifico sobre el problema que tengo pero basicamente es eso si no utilizo system("PAUSE") el programa no se finaliza con exito

Comment: Si finalizan con fallos no es por usar `system("PAUSE")` sino porque el programa hace algo raro

Comment: Tener o no tener `system("pause")` no debería influir en el número de fallos/excepciones que un programa tenga. No tiene sentido que tus programas finalicen con fallos si no tienen esa línea al final del código.

Comment: system("PAUSE") se utiliza para que podamos ver la ejecución ya que la computadora lo hace muy rápido, y return 0, es un aviso al SO que el programa acabo con éxito, si termina con otro numero le indica que termino de forma incorrecta.

Answer (score 5):

Acerca del `return`. Cuando se ejecuta un programa, siempre hay otro proceso que
es quién lo lanza. Puede ser la propia terminal el proceso que lanza a tu
programa, el sistema operativo si es un servicio del sistema, etc. En caso de
*Dev-C++* (o el *IDE* que estés utilizando), puedo suponer que el proceso
*Dev-C++* lanza una nueva terminal, y ese proceso terminal es quién lanza a
tu programa.

El `return` sirve para devolver, al proceso "que me lanzó a mí", un valor
indicando si el proceso terminó satisfactoriamente o no. Devolver `0` significa
que tu programa terminó satisfactoriamente, y un valor diferente de `0`
significa que no.

Por ejemplo, supón que tienes un programa que recibe un valor del usuario, que
debe ser un número mayor que cero para su funcionamiento natural. Si se recibe
un número `>0`, el programa hace lo que tenga que hacer, y si no, el programa no puede hacer su tarea, así que se considera una
situación errónea y se notifica. El código sería por ejemplo el siguiente:

```
int main()
{
    int i;

    std::cin >> i;

    if (i <= 0)
        return 1; // Problema.
    else {
        // Código para el funcionamiento normal del programa.
        return 0; // El programa terminó satisfactoriamente.
    }
}
```

De esta forma, cuando se ejecute tu proceso, cuando finalice, el proceso que ha
llamado a tu programa puede saber si tu programa terminó satisfactoriamente o
no. Evidentemente, puedes devolver el valor que quieras. Por ejemplo, puedes
indicar diferentes valores de retorno para indicar el tipo de error específico:

```
int main()
{
    int i;

    std::cin >> i;

    if (i == 0)
        return 1; // Se recibió un cero.
    else if (i < 0)
        return 2; // Se recibió un uno.
    else {
        // Código para el funcionamiento normal del programa.
        return 0; // El programa terminó satisfactoriamente.
    }
}
```

Con esos valores de retorno, el proceso llamante (si sabe lo que significa cada
valor de retorno de tu programa), puede actuar de una manera u otra según el
error específico producido.

Si tu programa no tiene ninguna sentencia `return`, el compilador te añade un
`return 0;` al final de tu programa:

```
int main()
{
    // Código del programa.

    // return 0; // Implícito si no lo escribes tú.
}
```

Ahora, ¿para qué vale el `system("pause")`? La función `system` permite ejecutar
cualquier comando que acepte el lenguaje de terminal de tu sistema
operativo. Por ejemplo, en Windows, dentro de `system`, puedo poner cualquier
comando en lenguaje DOS. En Linux, podría escribir cualquier comando escrito en
*Bash*, por ejemplo.

¿Para qué necesitas `system("pause")`? Pues resulta que *Dev-C++*, por defecto,
cuando finaliza tu programa, cierra la terminal que *Dev-C++* abrió para
ejecutar tu programa. Al llamar a `system("pause")`, el programa se bloquea
hasta que el usuario escriba algo. De esta manera, mantienes la terminal abierta
y puedes ver el resultado de tu programa hasta que hagas click en un botón.

En *CodeBlocks*, si no me equivoco, no te haría falta el `system("pause")`, dado
que *CodeBlocks*, por defecto, no cierra la terminal cuando termina tu
programa.

**Conclusión:** El hecho de que tu programa se cierre, y no veas el resultado,
  no es porque se esté lanzando ningún tipo de excepción, si no porque tu
  programa finaliza correctamente y `Dev-C++` te ha cerrado la terminal. El
  valor de `return` no tiene nada que ver aquí. Podrías quitarlo (el compilador
  te lo reañadiría), o cambiar el valor de retorno, que el resultado que verás
  será el mismo. `system("pause")` te permite hacer que tu programa espere a que
  el usuario pulse una tecla, y por tanto, manteniendo la terminal
  abierta. `system("pause")` solo te hace falta en algunos IDEs (`Dev-C++`) y
  `pause` es un comando del sistema exclusivo de Windows. En Linux `pause` no
  existe.

**NOTA:** Un valor de retorno diferente de cero no significa que tu programa contenga errores, o que el programa haya fallado desde un punto de vista interno. El programa termina bien desde un punto de vista totalmente funcional sea cual sea el valor de retorno. Es decir, el proceso termina limpiamente, solo que un valor de retorno diferente de cero indica que "el proceso ha terminado bien pero no ha podido hacer lo que se supone que debería hacer".

Answer (score 4):

Si el motivo para buscar una alternativa a `system(“PAUSE”)` es únicamente el **observar la salida**, las respuestas de [Peregring-lk](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/33939/22395) y de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/33931/22395) explican muy bien las opciones.

Sin embargo, si lo que se desea es evitar el uso de `system(“PAUSE”)` por alguna de las siguiente razones:

1. Porque es **dependiente del Sistema Operativo** (existe en Windows/DOS pero no en Linux/Unix)
2. Porque **hace mal uso de los recursos** (es costoso en términos de procesamiento)

Se debería en su lugar implementar soluciones en C++ nativo, por ejemplo:

```
cin.get();
```

Lo cual hace que el programa sea más eficiente, y evita una mala practica (aunque bastante común).

La estructura de un programa sería así:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // programa

    cout<<"Fin del programa" <<endl;
    cin.get(); // hace que la ejecucíon se detenga hasta que se presione enter

    return 0; 
}
```

Nota: el equivalente en C nativo, para lograr esto es:

```
getchar();
```

Comment: Coincido contigo en que es una mala práctica... Pero no olvidemos que si se usa es porque los métodos estándar no son capaces de impedir un _echo_ en la consola.

Comment: Hay cosas que deben ser mejoradas en c++ y la gestión de la consola es una de ellas

Comment: @eferion Un IDE no debería cerrarte la terminal. No es problema de la gestión de C++ con consolas. C/C++ solo entienden de entrada y salida estándar. Si Dev-C++ cierra la terminal (y por tanto, cierra ambos ficheros), no es problema del lenguaje, sino de Dev-C++.

Comment: Aunque entiendo que @Peregring-lk tiene razón al decir que el problema (el no poder observar la salida de un programa luego de su ejecución) es del IDE, estoy de acuerdo que en C++ se pudieran implementar mejoras a gestión de la consola. Mejorar la gestión de consola quizás ayudaría a evitar que tantos programadores abandonen C++.

Comment: @Monpeco Que C++ estandarice el comportamiento de la terminal añadiría restricciones innecesarias a las terminales, que tendrían que adaptarse a las especificaciones de C++. El tema creo que da para un digno análisis, pero todas las vías llevarían a callejones sin salida, supongo.

Comment: Exacto! podríamos pasar toda la vida discutiendo del tema, y nunca llegar a una respuesta. Igual muy interesante poder hablar de este tipo de cosas. Saludos.

Comment: @Monpeco Además es simple, C++ solo entiende de su entrada estándar (`std::cin`), salida estandar (`std::cout`), salida de errores estándar (`std::cerr`), y su salida de log estándar (`std::log`). Si esos "ficheros" están enlazados a ficheros de disco o de ram, a la entrada y salida de la terminal (si es que se ejecuta sobre una terminal; podría no darse el caso), o a sockets de red, es responsabilidad del entorno donde se ejecuta el programa (por ejemplo, podría no haber manera de especificar un `std::log` diferente a `std::cout` en ciertos sistemas operativos).

Comment: @peregring-lk. ¿me podrías decir en que momento he mencionado yo lo del IDE? Yo he hablado del lenguaje, y más concretamente de la librería estándar. Con la librería de base de phyton o c# o Java puedes hacer maravillas... Mientras que yo aún no he visto un producto completo haciendo uso únicamente de la librería estándar de c++

Comment: @peregring-lk si la librería estándar mejorase sus capacidades sobre la consola sería abstrayendo conceptos, no forzando a nadie a adaptarse. Un ejemplo son los hilos en c++11. En Linux funcionan diferente respecto a Windows... El que esté en la librería estándar te permite usar un código común independiente del SO que haya debajo

Comment: @eferion No por reabrir el debate, pero me ha llegado una notificación nueva por un voto y he releído los comentarios. Por añadir algo más, en C++, la "consola" es referida de manera genérica por el estándar como "interactive devices", y el significado de un "interactive device" es "implementation defined" de acuerdo al estándar de C++, y la máquina abstracta definida por el lenguaje dice que: la implementación [a.k.a, el compilador] no tiene por qué seguir las reglas del lenguaje siempre y cuándo produzca el mismo "comportamiento observable" que si las respetase.

Comment: @eferion Esto último se llama la "as-if rule", y el comportamiento observable se define como: el efecto sobre los ficheros, las variables volatiles, y los "interactive devices". Así que podemos decir que la única "gestión de consola"  estandarizada es, en resumen, que se debe respetar el efecto sobre los dispositivos interactivos sin importar las transformaciones de código (optimización) que el compilador aplique sobre tu programa. No es decir mucho pero es lo único que dice. Por cierto, ¿podrías poner algún ejemplo de "gestión de consola"? Porque la verdad, nunca he sabido a qué te referías.

Comment: @Peregring-lk por ejemplo poder posicionar el cursor en una posición aleatoria, poder usar colores, leer caracteres sin echo, limpiar la consola... son cosas que no se pueden hacer sin recurrir a terceros. Por ese motivo abundan tantos usos de `system`, por ejemplo

Comment: @eferion Pero eso ya lo ofrecen "third-parties", como [rxterm](https://github.com/LoopPerfect/rxterm), al igual que pasa con Python o el lenguaje que sea. Seguro que todas las herramientas que tienen los lenguajes que citas, también son librerías externas y no parte del núcleo del lenguaje (en este contexto, incluyo las librerías estándares como núcleo del lenguaje). Incluso si así fuera, C++ es un lenguaje estandarizado con estricta retrocompatibilidad; el riesgo de añadir características de muy difícil definición es demasiado alto. Se aprende a usar la librería correspondiente y punto.

Comment: @Peregring-lk tu compara la libreria base de c# o java con la ofrecida con c++... si te mueves en c++17 todavia puede salvarse por los pelos, pero aun asi hay muchas carencias (sockets, puertos, interfaz gráfica, bases de datos ...) yo siempre he criticado que solo con la libreria estandar de c++ es imposible hacer una aplicación completa

Comment: @eferion Pero tienes `boost`, que es casi una extensión a la librería estándar y que se utiliza como base de experiencia antes de meterlo en C++. Para que una librería pase a formar parte de boost, tiene que pasar por una serie de pruebas, y para que una librería de boost pase a la std, necesita un mínimo de dos años de experiencia en implementación y uso, luego se establece un "working group" del comité para esa librería, y si el comité central lo acepta, entonces pasa a la std. Como verás, C++ es un lenguaje muy estricto y de ahí que tarde tanto en tener nuevas carácterísticas.

Comment: @Peregring-lk aun asi con boost tampoco sacas una aplicación completa. Necesitas mínimo algo tipo Qt para no tener que reinventar la rueda varias veces

Comment: @eferion Sí eso es verda. Pero por las mismas razones. Hubo un proposal para añadir GUIs 2d para empezar por algo, pero no hay acuerdo generalizado acerca de las mejores prácticas que guarden un compromiso entre máxima eficiencia, mejor diseño, etc. Qt por ejemplo hace un uso innecesario de llamadas virtuales, los modelos deberían ser paramétricos y trabajar con rangos (+ señales) por máxima reusabilidad y máxima eficiencia, están acoplados a la GUI, etc. El problema no está en C++, sino en definir las características de una librería gráfica ideal.

Comment: @Peregring-lk nos agobiamos demasiado con el rendimiento cuando la inmensa mayoría de las veces no es un problema... ademas un uso demasiado centrado en el rendimiento suele ir en contra de la usabilidad

Comment: @eferion Estoy de acuerdo, y sin embargo, pa mi gusto, Qt no es tan usable cuando quieres empezar a hacer cosas complejas. Especialmente con el uso de modelos, que es mi gran pega (no soporto ni los índices, y en especial, los roles, que solo tienen sentido para su interacción con la vista; no hay separación entre "model_data" y "model_view" como se suele llamar). Respecto a C++, "la mayoría" no suele valer, dado que C++ es un lenguaje orientado a expertos (lo puede usar cualquiera pero el comité le suele dar prioridad a los usos más críticos).

Comment: @Peregring-lk es la losa de c++ 

Answer (score 2):

Si estás en entorno Windows puedes usar:

```
#include <conio.h>

std::cout << "Pulse una tecla para continuar...";
_getch();
```

Si estás en Linux puedes probar con la librería [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29):

```
std::cout << "Pulse una tecla para continuar...";
getch();
```

También, navegando por la versión inglesa de StackOverflow, encontré un [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux) en el que proponen otra alternativa:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static struct termios old, new;

/* Initialize new terminal i/o settings */
void initTermios(int echo) 
{
  tcgetattr(0, &old); /* grab old terminal i/o settings */
  new = old; /* make new settings same as old settings */
  new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON; /* disable buffered i/o */
  new.c_lflag &= echo ? ECHO : ~ECHO; /* set echo mode */
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new); /* use these new terminal i/o settings now */
}

/* Restore old terminal i/o settings */
void resetTermios(void) 
{
  tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
}

/* Read 1 character - echo defines echo mode */
char getch_(int echo) 
{
  char ch;
  initTermios(echo);
  ch = getchar();
  resetTermios();
  return ch;
}

/* Read 1 character without echo */
char getch(void) 
{
  return getch_(0);
}

/* Read 1 character with echo */
char getche(void) 
{
  return getch_(1);
}

/* Let's test it out */
int main(void) {
  char c;
  printf("(getche example) please type a letter: ");
  c = getche();
  printf("\nYou typed: %c\n", c);
  printf("(getch example) please type a letter...");
  c = getch();
  printf("\nYou typed: %c\n", c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ups ahora que me doy cuenta tambien se puede hacer string a;
  cout << "Introduce" << endl;
  cin >> a; como siempre gracias esta resuelto, de tanto compilar no me di cuenta que con un cin o getch() el problema esta resuelto

Comment: Las opciones que te propongo permiten capturar la tecla sin hacer _echo_ en la consola

Answer (score 0):

```
system("pause");
```

No es una función la cual sea un estándar para usar en cualquier programa para que no se cierre, lo correcto como en cualquier aplicación de windows es hacerlo bien, tu necesitas que el programa este atento a las peticiones del usuario, te recomiendo mientras tanto que aprendas mas a fondo sobre la API de windows, y leas acerca de mensajes enviados por el usuario:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx

ahora no es necesario si estas recién aprendiendo y no tienes mucho conocimiento avanzado, para ello solo basta con añadir a tu código:

```
while(GetMessage(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Esto hará estar atento a los mensajes del usuario el cual puedes aprender con el tiempo, eso si siempre ten en cuenta de que esto se coloca al final del principal antes del retorno:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    // do some stuffs...
    while(GetMessage(0, 0, 0, 0));
    return 0;
}
```

Edición: Yo he puesto esto por la razón de que dicha función `system("pause");` es un estándar de windows, lo cual es muy lógico que el se refiere a windows.