# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar un arreglo bidimensional solo por su primera columna?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Mi arreglo es de  `xy[n][2]` en el que el usuario ingresa una cantidad  `n`de filas, y la cantidad de columnas son 2, pero cuando el programa me va a dar los números ya ordenados, su coordenada Y se altera, osea, no va con respecto a la X. Por ejemplo si el usurario da los puntos:

(9,5),(3,4),(8,2),(4,1)

el programa los ordena de esta manera:

(3,5),(4,4),(8,2),(9,1)

Me deja la segunda columna en el mismo lugar, y no se va junto con su primera columna ya ordenada. El orden correcto debería de ser así:

(3,4),(4,1),(8,2),(9,5)

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int n;
cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad de números a ingresar: "<<endl;
cin>>n;

int xy[n][2];
cout<<"Escriba los puntos x,y"<<endl;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
        cout<<i<<" : ";
        cin>>xy[i][j];
    }
}

cout<<"Los numeros son: "<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
        cout<<xy[i][j]<<",";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

int k=0;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<2;j++){

        for (int l=i+1; l<n;l++) {
            if (xy[i][j] > xy[l][j]) {
                k=xy[i][j];
                xy[i][j]=xy[l][j];
                xy[l][j]=k;
            }
        }
    }
}

cout<<"Los numeros ingresados ordenados son: "<<endl;
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    for (int j=0;j<2;j++){
        cout<<xy[i][j]<<",";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
getch();

}
```

**El objetivo del código es que lea coordenadas xy de un punto, y después esas coordenadas las ordene con respecto al eje x, de mayor a menor, tendría que ordenar para ello de menor a mayor la primera columna del arreglo y después que su segunda columna no se desordene**

Psdt:
Soy nueva en la programación y con las clases en linea algunos temas son mas difíciles de entender, estuve investigando en google pero no he encontrado nada que me ayude. Agradecería su apoyo, es para un proyecto.

Comment: hola, si es necesario usar un arreglo bidimensional porque esto es solo una pequeña parte del proyecto. Utilizo el modo gráfco de turbo c en mi universidad y utilizo ese arreglo para obtener coordenadas y dibujar, además lo tengo incluido en un montón de funciones y si cabiara el arreglo tendría que cambiar todo el código. Si pudiera ayudarme, se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > ¿Cómo puedo ordenar un arreglo bidimensional solo por su primera columna?

Imaginemos que tenemos este *array* bidimensional (donde `i` representa el número de fila y `j` número de columna):

```cpp
 j=0   j=1 
[ 9    5 ] -> i = 0
[ 3    4 ] -> i = 1
[ 8    2 ] -> i = 2
[ 4    1 ] -> i = 3
```

Para poder intercambiar la coordenada `[9  5]` con `[3  4]`, necesitamos seguir unos pasos:

**1.-** Si el valor anterior es mayor que el valor siguiente con respecto a la primera columna, debemos hacer el cambio. Entonces así quedaría la coordenada:

```cpp
[3  5]  [9  4]
```

**2.-** Luego de hacer el cambio entre el `9` y `3`, necesitamos intercambiar las columnas con respecto a los valores de esas filas que hemos intercambiado anteriormente. Entonces la coordenada final queda así:

```cpp
[3  4]  [9  5]
```

Y así sucesivamente debemos hacer por cada coordenada.

En código sería exactamente lo mismo. He creado dos funciones:

- Para intercambiar los valores.
- Para ordenar las coordenadas con respecto al eje `x` de menor a mayor.

Código C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

const int N = 4;
const int M = 2;

/* 
    Para intercambiar los valores de cada fila y columna. 
    Los parámetros p1 y p2 son referencias y esto es para intercambiar los datos entre direcciones de memoria.
*/
void intercambiar(int& p1, int& p2)
{
    int aux = p1;
    p1 = p2;
    p2 = aux;
}

/* Ordena de menor a mayor las coordenadas. Usa el algoritmo de burbuja mejorado. */
void ordenarCoordenadas(int xy[][M])
{
    bool cambio = false;
    int len = N;
    while(1)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i != len; ++i)
        {
            //Si el valor anterior es mayor al valor siguiente, hacemos el intercambio
            if(xy[i - 1][0] > xy[i][0])
            {
                //Esta primera llamada debe intercambiar los valores con respecto a los filas
                intercambiar(xy[i][0], xy[i - 1][0]);
                //Esta segunda llamada debe intercambiar los valores con respecto a las columnas pero usando las filas anteriormente.
                intercambiar(xy[i][1], xy[i - 1][1]);
                cambio = true;
            }
        }
        //Si el array está ordenado, no necesitamos seguir iterando.
        if(!cambio) break;
        //Decrementamos la variable porque sabemos que los últimos elementos del array están ya ordenados.
        --len;
        cambio = false;
    }
}
```

Código de prueba:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int xy[N][M] =
    {
        {9,5},
        {3,4},
        {8,2},
        {4,1}
    };
    ordenarCoordenadas(xy);
    for(int i = 0; i != N; ++i)
        printf("(%d, %d)\n", xy[i][0], xy[i][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Resultado en pantalla:**

```cpp
(3, 4)
(4, 1)
(8, 2)
(9, 5)
```

**Observaciones:**

**1.-** Los [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (Variable-length array) no se incluyeron en el estándar de C++, por lo tanto, queda a disposición del compilador si lo acepta o no, sin embargo, esto hace que el código pierda portabilidad.

Esta línea de código es la que ocasionaría un error de compilación:

```cpp
int xy[n][2];
```

Ya que en C++ los tamaños de cada *array* con almacenamiento [estático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asignaci%C3%B3n_de_memoria#Asignaci%C3%B3n_est%C3%A1tica_de_memoria) o [automático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asignaci%C3%B3n_de_memoria#Asignaci%C3%B3n_autom%C3%A1tica_de_memoria), deben ser expresiones constantes (números que se conozcan en tiempo de compilación).

Una posible solución es usar una [matriz dinámica](http://mauricioavilesc.blogspot.com/2015/08/matriz-dinamica-en-c.html#:~:text=Matriz%20din%C3%A1mica%20en%20C%2B%2B,determine%20en%20tiempo%20de%20ejecuci%C3%B3n.).

**2.-** La cabecera `conio.h` no es estándar. Si quieres pausar el programa al final del `main`, debes usar [cin.get()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/33927/alternativa-a-systempause-c).

Answer (score 1):

Parece que tu objetivo es trabajar con pares de datos más que con arreglos bidimensionales, una solución sencilla sería pasar tu arreglo a una colección de `std::pair` y usar las herramientas de la cabecera `<algorithm>` para ordenar:

```
using arreglo = std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>;

int n;
std::cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de números a ingresar:\n";
std::cin >> n;

arreglo valores(n);

// pedir valores...

// Ordenamos por la primera columna.
std::sort(valores.begin(), valores.end(),
    [](const auto&a, const auto &b) { return a.first < b.first; });
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFNTsMwEIXXmVOMitQmUqj4KRKkITsWSNwAWDiJGyyl48h2qlZVL8aWgwXHSWhDYWN7xjNvPj9nVXWZlYyKprkQlJV1zjEWUhvF2TqBY46VhVTCfIySG54ZqRIAQQbXTJAfwB68NqIleNrkUZTJ2mAc4@SZCsU1x5JhxsiInOVoRejrc82V1MhQuAqmojea/LQLwiRp5cCrta1AphQvSomP6Ao6htidKyZUbKeHVsokidUYijeslFbbp6AVGoM96UyJlGFpIaqajN224c4xgLeSCn1WG4lTd4fRoBWAZ9/6S2sbYYs@Ynd985VQ2izPGnb/NmieScrt3WEg1lIZv58@T3nR@h0OOHNOeRu@vvu2TxtsoacsxGOE0zTAPSpuakXIOiSMMe3h8PCHOy/WDqq7L@o/KLdHqXJO7qQlRadmnc47t2ysPvNn7XbikJsZ4uSY7nxw@aCf07/gagmHplnAA9zBLSzgHm7seg34DQ)</kbd>.

Si realmente necesitas que sea un arreglo bidimensional, deberás pedir la memoria adecuadamente, a no ser que crees el arreglo con el operador `new`, su tamaño debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación, así que tu código para crear el arreglo debería ser así:

```
int n;
std::cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de números a ingresar:\n";
std::cin >> n;

using doblete = int[2];
doblete *xy = new doblete[n];
```

Pero esto complica mucho la ordenación, ya que no podemos trabajar directamente con `std::sort`.

#### Propuesta.

Dado que quieres trabajar con coordenadas crea un objeto de coordenadas que ya incorpore la función de comparación, lectura y escritura:

```
struct Punto
{
    int x{}, y{};
    bool operator<(const Punto &otro) const
    {
        return x < otro.x;
    }
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &i, Punto &p)
{
    i >> p.x;
    i >> p.y;
    return i;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Punto &p)
{
    return o << '(' << p.x << ", " << p.y << ')';
}
```

De esta manera, todo tu código de lectura, ordenación y escritura podría quedar así:

```
int n;
std::cout << "Ingrese la cantidad de números a ingresar:\n";
std::cin >> n;

std::vector<Punto> valores(n);

std::cout << "Escriba los puntos x,y\n";

for (auto &punto : valores)
    std::cin >> punto;

std::sort(valores.begin(), valores.end());

std::cout << "Los puntos ordenados son:\n";

for (const auto &punto : valores)
    std::cout << punto << '\n';
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVHLbuMwDDyHX0GkwEYGvME@usCuY/jWQ4Ee9gN6UWQ1FeCQhiwXCQL/WK/9sKwky@k6aHWwTHI4MxRV235VjaTd@XxjSDV9rbE03Dmr5b6C95xsdmyNe54lX7RybCsAj@@Vw789OYYToD@GHB5OQ47H07CJmS1zg9xqK31TKRRTl1rwCzvLGcZUxI4c4Vjtekt4wBIDaH0YyQbwrF63LgozuvUkibuqxLxg8kmnzSZ7WFXYTmwpOo5RkjQbGJIEX0uUpbgq5Dgb6CKUyBjLEldiFS4vG65ljssxPMZitoqC4eH20pAIDIsQ0QYWUU1x72LnPe2s7jQ2EpUkZ2pZo18Ivb3uteUOpX/@gJC2eKTlpd1QmNPTpcS4vzJarvBFNux7BGUXwEXwrlPWbCU2nrwN8A4P@TFyw@KJLQrZx7Hj9MXElcHCzzBTjwjvaJg0OrZOJPx6q3dh8nwiWGuqRfaBoYd3I2xrTbL2fx1T8b@ncSOfOZszjvWwh0daBYa0uG9@KefzLfyBX/ATbuE3/PDf74D/AA)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchas gracias @PaperBirdMaster, tu respuesta me ha sido muy útil en el compilador dev-c++, pero intento pasar código de dev-c++ a turbo c, que es el compilador en el que esto haciendo el proyecto, y lamentablemente turo c no incluye la librería  `#include <algorithm>` ni  `#include <algorithm.h>`, aunque si me ha sido de mucha utilidad, ya que no sabía del uso de ésta librería, y las funciones que tiene me parecen muy útiles.

Comment: Si tu idea era programar en [tag:c], no deberías etiquetar la pregunta como [tag:c++]. Son lenguajes distintos.

Comment: Tienen bastante compatibilidad, pero tienes razón @PaperBirdMaster.